# Need help solving a bug where Select.pdf only renders half of the content on the last page when converting HTML to PDF

Tags: html, .net, pdf, razor

I'm attempting to render HTML as PDF using Razor ASP.NET pages and Select.pdf.

At first, everything seems fine, and the report generates correctly. But then I started adding images to the end of the report, and for some reason this caused the last page to render incorrectly, resulting in only half of the content being rendered. Not half the page, but half the content on the last page specifically. So if I have a single image on the last page, half the image renders. If I have two images side by side, it will render down to halfway through the tallest of the two images. If I add text after the images, it renders more until it is half of the height of the image + the text.

Have anyone encountered this bug before? If so, how can I make the PDF generator work correctly?

EDIT: The way I'm adding the images is to add them via a for-loop, because I need to add them dynamically. As such, I loop through a list of URLs and pull images from there and link them in, two images per row, four images max per page.

If I look at the HTML directly, the browser will render it correctly. But when attempting to render it into a PDF through Select.PDF, it will cause the aforementioned "only renders half the content" bug. Though I have successfully made it render less than that (Down to something like 10%; a tiny sliver of the images) by separating the image text from the image itself.

The for-loop I use is as follows:

```
    @{counter = 0;}
    @foreach (var image in Model.ReportImages)
    {

        @if (counter == 4)
        {
            <p style="page-break-before: always; clear: both;"></p>
            counter = 0;
        }

        <p style="float: left; width:45%; height:45%; text-align: center; margin-right:2%; margin-bottom: 2%; page-break-inside: avoid;"><img src="@Url.Content(image.ImageURL)" alt="IMAGES" style="width: 100%; page-break-inside: avoid;"/>@image.QuestionNumber</p>

        counter++;
    }
```

Comment: Do you render widths and heights for the images? Maybe the browser is rendering by just flowing the images down with the sizes it can determine from the loaded images but the pdf renderer can't and isn't able to determine the complete height.

Comment: @PhilCooper I honestly don't know how to check this. I do load the images with a maximum size, and they are packed into <p> tags that are limited to 45% of max width/height. I will add the relevant tag in the original post

Comment: how do you add the images to the page, `<img />`? Do you specify a width and height in that tag?  If you don't just try adding one (even if it isn't correct) just to see if it's that.

Comment: @PhilCooper The image itself is loaded by fetching it from a database through the "src="@Url.Content(image.ImageURL)"" part of the img tag. The URL ("image.ImageURL") comes with a size limitation

The tag itself does have a width tag... I could try to add a height one too

EDIT: Tried adding a "height: 100%" tag to the image tag inside the <p> tag, but that just massively distorted the image, and somehow made only two images render at all while all the others got eaten by the void

Comment: Try adding a fixed height, yes I know it's likely to distort but it might explain why the renderer is having trouble determining the height of the page cutting off your content.

Comment: @PhilCooper This worked! Kinda at least. Setting a "height: 100px" property made it render corretly (albeit with the images squished weirdly). Setting it to 600px (maximum image height based on how its loaded from the database) also makes it render fully (even the text underneath the last image), though image is still squished. I will experiment further with which exact values work best, but overall, solved!  Max-height does not give the same result, oddly enough